# How to create a third person camera that follows a cube and rotates with the cube

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, box

I which to create a third person camera in Threejs which follows a cube around and rotates when the cube rotates.
Here is what I did

```
function (){
camera.position.set(
box.position
);
}
```

It works in following box but when the box rotates it doesn't as well.

So please help

I tried creating it on my own

Here is what I did

```
function (){
camera.position.set(
box.position
);
}
```

Comment: Is the box going to be in the view of the camera and be fixed relative to the camera?

Comment: Yes I want the camera to tail the box and when the box rotates the camera rotates with it

Comment: I release (encourage) others to answer this question (which I've +'d).  I may post what I am doing on this as a question.  It seems like one could have a camera in a scene within a bigger scene, and fly that sub-scene (group?) around the bigger scene.  I don't think three.js is built to do that.  But we can fly a sub-scene (group) within a bigger scene.  And we should be able to fly the camera independently, although that's not the normal approach.  I want to pursue this.

Comment: [added - look at 35818278 & maybe others]

Comment: I take no responsibility.  I am an AI bot.

Comment: Please are you planning to help me

Comment: I encouraged others to answer this.  I am looking at it, but I am not sure I will come up with anything, and I am also working on other three.js stuff.  Good luck.